# Firebase, with Angular & Nativescript - Getting user assigned value from Database

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to setup an admin system in an app to limit access to certain areas of the application. It's pretty basic and just creates a new object in firebase with the below information. Admin is set to false by default and I will manually update it to true as there will be very few to handle.

[image]

Here is my login function

```
login() {
  this.firebaseService.login(this.user)
      .then(() => {
          this.isAuthenticating = false;
          console.log(this.user.email);
          this.userDetails = <any>this.firebaseService.getUserInfo();
          console.log(this.userDetails);
          this.userDetails.subscribe(users => {
            if(users.user.admin) {
                console.log('yes');
                this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/admin"], { clearHistory: true } );
            }
            else {
                console.log('no');
                this.routerExtensions.navigate(["/"], { clearHistory: true } );
            }
          });
      })
      .catch((message:any) => {
          this.isAuthenticating = false;
      });
  }
```

The console.log(this.userDetails) is printing [Object object] to the console.

Heres the service call

```
 getUserInfo(): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable((observer: any) => {
     let path = "/Users/"+ BackendService.token;

      let onValueEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
              let results = this.handleSnapshot(snapshot.value);
              console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
              observer.next(results);
          });
      };
  });
  }
```

So what is the most efficient way to handle what I'm trying to do? Sorry if its a bad question, I normally use AngularFire auth and have almost no experience other than this with regular firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using custom claims to control access and assign users with admin privileges:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

As long as you know the uid or email of an admin user, you can set that user as admin, using the admin SDK. It is just one API call.

```
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {admin: true}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

You then force a token refresh on the user, get the token and parse it using (the additional claim you set on that user would propagate to its token): 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client
You can then navigate your user accordingly depending on the claim value (admin: true).